# how to create a component that will show the score

Tags: react-native

score image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDVRo.png)
I want to create a component in react-native which will display the score, the score can be different i.e it can be 65 or 45. Please go through the image link.

Comment: do you want that faded orange quarter circle in the back?

Comment: Yes. I need that as well

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const ScoreComponent = (props) => {
  return <View style={{backgroundColor:"white",width:50,height:50,borderRadius:25,borderWidth:1,borderColor:"red",alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"Center"}}>
    <Text style={{color:"blue"}}>{props.score}</Text>
  </View>
}
```

and use like this

```
<ScoreComponent score={65}  />
```

snack link https://snack.expo.io/@mehran.khan/score

Comment: But the score should be auto calculated not hard-coded

Comment: you are passing the score={65} , it is `prop` . you can pass anything you want like 45 or 65

Comment: Actually I am going to use that inside a render function that means it will be a card which is going to render whenever I add a new data for eg: it will be shown as Person 1 with 65 , Person 2 with 45, Person 3 with 20..... so I can't directly put the score as 65 or 45.

Answer (score 0):

I modified @Mehran Khan 's answer to include the orange quarter sphere in the background.

https://snack.expo.io/ZMjTm5ONv

```
const ScoreComponent = (props) => {
  return <View style={{backgroundColor:"white",width:50,height:50,borderRadius:25,borderWidth:1,borderColor:"red",alignItems:"center",justifyContent:"Center"}}>
    <Text style={{color:"blue"}}>{props.score}</Text>
  </View>
}

const ScoreContainer = () => {
  return <View style={{overflow: 'hidden', width: 55, height: 55, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}><ScoreComponent score={65} />
<View style={{zIndex: -10, width: 90, height: 90, borderRadius: 100, position: 'absolute', left: -45, bottom: -45, backgroundColor: 'rgba(240,100,0,0.3)'}}/>
  </View>;
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScoreContainer  />
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
    alignItems:"center",
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
 
});
```